# Check that the milestones of each project have been completed between the start and end dates of the project

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

Good morning! I'm a bit stuck with this question. I know it's not complicated (Because I'm pretty sure I'm close to the answer) But I've been Stuck for a bit now. I'm totally new to MySQL

**My database code :** https://srcb.in/OtFsESDjx5

I need to Give the total number of hours worked and the total amount earned per employee in all projects, including the employee's name and email address. (Expected result: idemploye, nomEmploye, adresseCourriel, nbrHeures, somme gagnée)

**So i tried this query :**

```
SELECT r.idEmploye, e.nomEmploye, e.adresseCourriel, r.nbrHeures, r.somme_gagnée
     FROM  (SELECT idEmploye,
                         sum(nbrHeure) AS nbrHeures,
                         sum(nbrHeure*PrixHeure) AS somme_gagnée
                   FROM  ressourcesprojet_
               GROUP BY  idEmploye
           ) AS r

INNER JOIN  employe_  AS e;
```

It gives me back to many columns, like it's repeating idemployee for every nomEmploye
[image: It gives me back to many columns, like it's repeating idemployee for every nomEmploye]

So i tried to remove the "Group By", because I thought that by grouping it I would be repeating it several times internally :

```
SELECT r.idEmploye, e.nomEmploye, e.adresseCourriel, r.nbrHeures, r.somme_gagnée
      FROM  (SELECT idEmploye,
                          sum(nbrHeure) AS nbrHeures,
                          sum(nbrHeure*PrixHeure) AS somme_gagnée
                    FROM  ressourcesprojet_
            ) AS r
 
JOIN  employe_  AS e;
```

And... it kinda worked?
Now, effectively, I only have 4 employees but everything that is r.idEmploye, r.nbrHeures, r.somme_gagnée it's "repeated". As if it just took the first one and repeated it multiple times for .r

[image: And... it kinda worked?]

As a last test, I said that possibly the best thing would be to create an INNER JOIN between e.nomEmploye = r.idEmploye
But I'm not sure that's it because it just doesn't select anything for me

```
SELECT r.idEmploye, e.nomEmploye, e.adresseCourriel, r.nbrHeures, r.somme_gagnée
      FROM  (SELECT idEmploye,
                          sum(nbrHeure) AS nbrHeures,
                          sum(nbrHeure*PrixHeure) AS somme_gagnée
                    FROM  ressourcesprojet_
                GROUP BY  idEmploye
            ) AS r
 
INNER JOIN employe_  AS e
    ON e.nomEmploye = r.idEmploye;
```

But, there it does not give me anything
[image: But, there it does not give me anything]

Thank you very much if you can clarify my doubt

Comment: I moved your example to a live SQL demo site: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hkYtcPTF4KoYEuXd1DKhkB/0

Comment: Do i replace the link "https://srcb.in" for the "db-fiddle.com" one?

Comment: Nope, it looks like the code you provided included some PRIMARY/FOREIGN KEYs that db-fiddle didn't like. So keep your code separate, I just wanted a live demo to tinker with.

Comment: Thanks for the DBFiddle, I used that as a starting point @WOUNDEDStevenJones

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of your expected result from this query.

Comment: Sorry it took me some time to respond, i actyally got the answer i needed!

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
SELECT e.idEmploye, e.nomEmploye, e.adresseCourriel, inner_q.nbrHeures, inner_q.somme_gagnee
FROM
( SELECT idEmploye, sum(nbrHeure) AS nbrHeures, sum(nbrHeure*PrixHeure) AS somme_gagnee
FROM  RessourcesProjet_ GROUP BY  idEmploye ) as inner_q     
JOIN Employe_ e
WHERE e.idEmploye = inner_q.idEmploye
```

Seems like what you wanted:

[image]

Thanks to WOUNDEDStevenJones for the DB Fiddle link.

Comment: This seems to work, but why would we write a sub-query here?

Comment: Probably not the most optimal; I feel the same but I cannot point out why.

Comment: I have written an answer without a subquery. Nevertheless, yours also seems to be correct at first glance, so I of course upvote it.

Comment: Oops, I happened to paste my query twice. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join by the criteria that the id is matching:

```
select RessourcesProjet_.idEmploye, sum(nbrHeure) AS nbrHeures, sum(nbrHeure*PrixHeure) AS somme_gagnee
from RessourcesProjet_
join Employe_
on RessourcesProjet_.idEmploye = Employe_.idEmploye
group by RessourcesProjet_.idEmploye;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just do a `JOIN` with your subquery (still using the `GROUP BY`) and `Employe_` tables:

```
SELECT
    r.idEmploye,
    e.nomEmploye,
    e.adresseCourriel,
    r.nbrHeures,
    r.somme_gagnee
FROM (
    SELECT
        idEmploye,
        SUM(nbrHeure) AS nbrHeures,
        SUM(nbrHeure*PrixHeure) AS somme_gagnee
    FROM
        RessourcesProjet_
    GROUP BY
        idEmploye
) AS r
JOIN Employe_ e ON e.idEmploye = r.idEmploye
```

Live example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hkYtcPTF4KoYEuXd1DKhkB/2 returns:

| idEmploye | nbrHeures | somme_gagnee | nomEmploye | adresseCourriel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1212 | 3000 | 105000 | Marie St-Jerome | marie.stjerome@ca |
| 1876 | 2500 | 102500 | Martin Rey | martin.rey@ca |
| 2231 | 750 | 46250 | Jean Pierre Bordeau | jean.bordeau@ca |
| 4354 | 2000 | 62000 | Louise Gagnon | louise.gagnon@ca |

Comment: If this isn't the exact data you're looking for, could you edit your question to include your expected result?

Comment: Oh! Yes! This is the data i was looking for. Sorry if my Frenchglish wasn't precise and Confused you Wounded xD. And also! Thank you !